# pip3 does not find a dependency for my package, though it exists

Tags: python, pip

I am creating a `setup.py` for my own package. My package requires a Python dependency 'rarfile'. So, in `setup.py`, I added:

```py
setup(
...
    install_requires=[ 'rarfile' ],
)
```

Unfortunately, when I build the package, upload it to test.pypi, and test installation, it fails complaining that there is no matching distribution for rarfile. What is strange is that I can manually install rarfile using pip3 without any problem and it works.

Testing install with pip3 on my package:

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ droidlysis 
Collecting droidlysis
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/e8/f7542484ba4acd6a2d079a22c29cd88dcf63cd8334ffa3de29fa5b0ea7a0/droidlysis-3.0.11.tar.gz (40kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 40kB 975kB/s 
Collecting rarfile==3.1 (from droidlysis)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rarfile==3.1 (from droidlysis) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rarfile==3.1 (from droidlysis)
```

Directly installing `rarfile` with pip3:

```
$ pip3 install rarfile==3.1
Collecting rarfile==3.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/0b/107dde3f330d04668e126932a09002ac47348841453aa0391634381fa087/rarfile-3.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: rarfile
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rarfile ... error
  Complete output from command /home/axelle/softs/myvirtualenvs/testdroidlysis/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yj6ptg3b/rarfile/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpnlukg8ugpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rarfile
  Running setup.py clean for rarfile
Failed to build rarfile
Installing collected packages: rarfile
  Running setup.py install for rarfile ... done
Successfully installed rarfile-3.1
```

Comment: `Failed building wheel for rarfile` does not look like the installation worked. Also the two commands differ. `pip3 install --no-cache-dir <your package>` and ``pip3 install rarfile`. One uses the cache, the other not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `--index-url URL` switch.

This will replace the default `pypi.org` and ignore it at all.
Use `--extra-index-url URL` to take into account the default pypi.org

The test index [does not exist `rarfile`](https://test.pypi.org/search/?q=rarfile)

Help of `pip install`:

```
...
Package Index Options:
  -i, --index-url <url>       Base URL of the Python Package Index (default
                              https://pypi.org/simple). This should point to a
                              repository compliant with PEP 503 (the simple
                              repository API) or a local directory laid out in
                              the same format.
  --extra-index-url <url>     Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition
                              to --index-url. Should follow the same rules as
                              --index-url.
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The `--index-url` option overwrites the default index url; it doesn't add to it.
Try with `--extra-index-url` instead:

```
$ pip3 install --no-cache-dir --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ droidlysis
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `--index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/`, and so `pip` is *only looking at that index and no others*.

There is no `https://test.pypi.org/project/rarfile` so the install indeed fails.

Either

- use multiple `--index-url` switches to include both `pypi.org/index` and `test.pypi.org/index`,
- or use `--extra-index-url` to *add* `test.pypi.org/index` to the locations to search